# いいね機能を作りたいのに外部キーが参照されなくてundefined method `id' for nil:NilClassになってしまう

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

いいね機能を実装しようとして、投稿ボタンを押したら、投稿一覧ページへ遷移するようにしたのですが、いいねボタンの部分でエラーになってしまいました。
参考にしたのはこちらの記事です
[Rails いいね機能のミニアプリを作ろう](https://qiita.com/keitah/items/12b50c86bcfa9cfb4db9#likerb)

エラーで引っかかってしまっているコードは以下です

```
  def already_liked?(post)
    self.likes.exists?(post_id: post.id)
  end
```

エラーメッセージは以下です。

```
NoMethodError in Posts#index

undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

そこで、問題のソースコードにあるところにあるコードをコメントアウトしたらエラー分は消えていいねは押せるようになったのですが、今度はその取消ができなくなってしまいました。
どうしたらいいかわかりません。

## 問題のソースコード

user.rb(userに関するモデル)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
    
  has_one_attached :image
  has_many :comments       
  has_many :posts
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :liked_posts, through: :likes, source: :post
 
  def already_liked?(post)
    self.likes.exists?(post_id: post.id)
  end


  with_options presence: true do
    validates :nickname
    validates :mania_histry
    validates :enjoy_point
    validates :email
    validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }
  end
end
```

post.rb(投稿に関するモデル)

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many_attached :images
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :likes
    has_many :liked_users, through: :likes, source: :user


    validates :content, presence: true

end
```

like.rb(いいね機能に関するモデル)

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :post
 belongs_to :user
end
```

### ここからはコントローラーです

以下は、いいね機能に関するコントローラーです

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @like = current_user.likes.create(post_id: params[:post_id])
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
  end

  def destroy
    @like = Like.find_by(post_id: params[:post_id], user_id: current_user.id)
    @like.destroy
    redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
  end
end
```

以下は、投稿に関するコントローラーです

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :update, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :find_post, only: [:edit, :update, :show, :destroy]

    def index
        @posts = Post.all
        @like = Like.new
      end

      def new
        @post = Post.new
        @like = Like.new

      end

    def show
    end
    
    
    def create
      @post = current_user
      @post = Post.create(post_params)
      if @post.save
        redirect_to root_path,notice:'投稿に成功しました'
        else
          redirect_to new_post_path,notice:'投稿に失敗しました'
        end
      end
    
      def edit
      end

      def update
        @post.update(post_params)
      end

      def destroy
        if @post.destroy
          redirect_to root_path,alert: '投稿を削除しました'
        else
          redirect_to root_path
        end
      end

      private

        def post_params
          params.require(:post).permit(:content, {images: []}).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
        end

        def find_post
          @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        end

        def force_redirect_unless_my_post
          return redirect_to root_path,alert:'権限がありません'if @post.user != current_user
        end
end
```

以下は、ビューです

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-block">
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <div class="content">
         <div class="user-about">
             <div class="image">
             <% if post.user.image.attached? %>
             <%= image_tag post.user.image %>
                <% else %>
            <%= image_tag no.user.png %>
                <% end %>
             </div>

         <div class="profile">
            <div class="name-history">
                <div class="name">

                <%= post.user.nickname %>


                </div>
                <div class="mania-histry">
                    <%= "学習歴:#{post.user.mania_histry}年" %>
                </div>
             </div>
             
             <div class="enjoy-point">
             <%= "楽しいポイント#{post.user.enjoy_point}"%>
             </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       
       <div class="text">
        <p><%= post.content %></p>
    </div>
        <% if post.images.attached? %>
        <% post.images.each do |image| %>
            <div class = 'images'>
                <%= image_tag image %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
         <div class="action-menu">
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
             <div class="like">
             <h3>いいね件数: <%= post.likes.count %></h3>
             <div class = 'like-button'>
                <% if current_user.already_liked?(post.id) %>
                <%= button_to 'いいねを取り消す', post_like_path(post), method: :delete %>
             <% else %>
               <%= button_to 'いいね', post_likes_path(post) %>
             <% end %>

            </div>
            </div>
            <% end %>
             <div class="comment">
                 
        </div>
         </div>

        </div>
        <% end %>


    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
     <div class="box">

     </div>
     <div class="box">
         
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## 試してみたこと

ご指摘させていただいたとおりにviewの48行目の
`<% if current_user.already_liked?(post.id) %>`の部分を
`<% if current_user.already_liked?(@post) %>`に変更してみましたが変化なしでした。
もう一つは、いいね機能に関するコントローラーのストロングパラメーターを

```
@like = current_user.likes.create(post_id: params[:post_id])
```

から

```
@like = current_user.likes.create(post_id: post_id)
```

に変更してみたのですが何も変わりませんでした。
likeコントローラーにnewメソッドがないからかなと思い、

```
  def new
    @like = Like.new
  end
```

を追加したあとにroutes.rbにもnewメソッドを追加、投稿のコントローラーの方にあった記述は削除しました、そうしたらエラー分が以下に変わりました。

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Posts#index

No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"likes", :post_id=>#<Post id: 1, content: "asdf", created_at: "2021-03-26 23:40:56", updated_at: "2021-03-26 23:40:56", user_id: 1>}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

post.idは取得できているようですが、全部の情報を受け取ってしまっているみたいでできないのかなって考えたのですが、その次のアクションプランがわかりません。

Answer (score 1):

こちらの記事を参考にしました。
[【Rails】いいね機能完全版！同期いいね、いいね数の表示、非同期いいね、アイコン表示、それぞれの実装方法についてまとめて解説](https://techtechmedia.com/favorite-function-rails/)

そして、ビューファイルの記述(いいね機能の部分)を

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <div class="like">
    <h3>いいね件数: <%= post.likes.count %></h3>
    <div class='like-button'>
      <% if current_user.liked_by?(post.id) %>
       　<td><%= link_to 'いいねを外す', destroy_like_path(post), class: "like-link", method: :DELETE %></td>
         <i class="fa fa-heart unlike-btn"></i>
      <% else %>
         <td><%= link_to 'いいね', create_like_path(post), class: "like-link", method: :create %></td>
         <i class="fa fa-heart like-btn"></i>
      <% end %>
```

ユーザーモデルの記述を

```
def liked_by?(post_id)
  likes.where(post_id: post_id).exists?
end
```

に変更したら解決できました。

Answer (score 0):

`already_liked?` メソッドは Post クラスのインスタンスが引数に渡されることを期待しています。

```
def already_liked?(post)
  self.likes.exists?(post_id: post.id)
end
```

一方で元々のビューにおいては、`already_liked?` メソッドに対して整数を渡していました。

```
<% if current_user.already_liked?(post.id) %>
```

したがってこの部分で既に何かおかしいです。どちらかに揃える必要があります。たとえば参考になさっている記事では Post クラスのインスタンスが渡されるようにしていますね。

「試してみたこと」として追記されたビューにおいては、`post` ではなく `@post` を渡していました。

```
<% if current_user.already_liked?(@post) %>
```

PostsController#index のおいては `@posts` は存在しますが `@post` は存在しません。`post` を渡すようにすべきです。

Comment: @nekketsuuuさんありがとうございます。質問内容を編集したときに修正漏れがありました。現在底の部分は修正しておりますのでもしよろしければ回答していただけると大変助かります。